# Wireshark: there are no interfaces on which a capture can be done

Tags: wireshark

I've made all steps described in [wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges), but I still get next error message

> There are no interfaces on which a
>   capture can be done.

Where I've made a mistake?

```
$ groups dima
lp wheel games video audio optical storage power wireshark users
$ ls -l /usr/bin/dumpcap 
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root wireshark 77000 Jul 29 12:07 /usr/bin/dumpcap
$ getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap 
/usr/bin/dumpcap = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip
```

Comment: What does `strace dumpcap -D` print?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your user to a wireshark group, add the dumpcap to wireshark group and add permissions to dumpcap

```
   # chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
   # chmod 7450 /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

The path can be /usr/bin/dumpcap or /usr/sbin/dumpcap

Comment: Don't you need to `sudo` those commands, since you're running as a user?

Comment: "You should add your user to a wireshark group".  He *is* in that group - see the output of "groups dima", which includes "wireshark".  And dumpcap does have extra privileges - see the output of "getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap".  The question is whether those privileges are working; that's why I asked him to try `strace dumpcap -D`, to see what dumpcap is trying to do when you ask it to list devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the capture using tcpdump at the command line, then open the resulting pcap file with Wireshark or something else. Like so:

```
sudo tcpdump -w test.pcap -vv -i wlan0
```

Comment: If Wireshark isn't showing any devices, dumpcap probably isn't showing any devices, which means that dumpcap probably can't open any devices, which means that there's a good chance that tcpdump can't open any devices, either.  (BTW, "-v" is pointless with "-w" - "-w" means "save packets to a file rather than printing them", and "-v" means "print packets verbosely.)